# Solving an IVP with separation of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this equation:

$$(e^{2y} - y) \cos(x)\, dy/dx = e^x \sin(x) \text{ with initial condition } y(0) = 0. $$

I already tried to separate the variables, but I couldn't integrate $e^x \tan(x)$. Am I approaching this problem the right way?

Comment: It's not possible to solve using elementary functions.

Answer (score 0):

$\bf hint:$ you can separate the variables to get $$\int_0^y\left( e^{2y} - y\right) \,  dy  = \int_0^x e^x \tan x  \, dx$$ on integration you get 
$$\frac{1}{2}\left( e^{2y} - y^2 - 1\right) = \int_0^x e^x \tan x \, dx$$
 The RHS integral is difficult, but you can write it in terms of hypergeometric functions:
$$ i e^x \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{i}{2},1;1-\frac{i}{2};-e^{2 i
    x}\right)-\left(\frac{2}{5}+\frac{i}{5}\right) e^{(1+2 i) x} \,
    _2F_1\left(1,1-\frac{i}{2};2-\frac{i}{2};-e^{2 i x}\right).$$

Comment: What happened to $\cos x$?

Comment: @Travis, thanks. i will see if i can find an antiderivative for $e^x \tan x.$

Comment: err try integration by parts on the right hand side of the equation.

Comment: @usukidoll, $\int e^x \tan x dx = e^x \tan x - \int \frac{e^x}{\cos^2 x} dx$ leads to a dead end.

Comment: oh geez. that is crazy 0_O